# cannot understand AnonymousClass5 on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

first of all, sorry for this very weird question.

i'm completely new on android as well as java programing. and i lost my primarily written source code while repairing my computer. so i extracted back the source code from compiled apk file. and what i got completely confused me.

all other files are ok. but on one of my activity class file, i found a term '**AnonymousClass5**'. i don't know if i wrote this myself or it was replacement for something that was made while extracting apk file.

i searched the web, but couldn't find any reference. here is the part of the code

```
public void processData() {
    String[] data = this.receiveddata.split("@-'''==='''///'''==='''-@");
    int datalen = data.length;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < datalen) {
        String[] data1 = data[i].split("@-''==='''-@");
        int sid = Integer.parseInt(data1[1]);
        .........................
        .........................
        AnonymousClass5 r8 = r0;
        final int i2 = sid;
        AnonymousClass5 r0 = new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1);
                .........................
                .........................
            }
        }
        textView.setOnClickListener(r8);
        i++;
        data = data2;
    }
}
```

its killing my hours. and i'm stuck at this point. so i'm seeking help from geniuses.

Sorry again for this weird problem and my little knowledge.

Comment: It is hard to guess without seeing the origignal code, but I suspect that it is the implementation of an anonymous interface, generated by the compiler, triggered by a lambda-expression in the original code. --- To prevent those problems in the future, I recommend using a [Version contol system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control), e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/) (through e.g. [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), [github](https://github.com/), [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like **AnonymousClass5** class in Java but I think while extracting the apk, this class was auto-generated by the compiler.

To solve the issue, you should replace the reference of **AnonymousClass5** with **View.OnClickListener** interface like the below code :

```
View.OnClickListener r0 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1);
            .........................
            .........................
        }
    }

textView.setOnClickListener(r8);
```

Comment: This actually removed the error notation from the app and now my project looks clean. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @BinodAnuj I am glad that it helped. Please upvote the answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I upvoted it but since my reputation is less, it is not showing publicly. Thank you again for your suggestion.